# Wordpress 404 Error when vieiwing php file direct

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a php file which holds a script within my wordpress theme folder which i am trying to view directly via a relative path in the browser ie: www.mywebsite.com/wp-content/themes/my-theme-name/file-in-question.php

however wordpress is giving a 404 error as soon as i try to view it directly.

I would create a template within wordpress but for the script to work i need to view it with the .php extension in the browser since its basically a custom search to another script outside wordpress which returns results like so:

www.mywebsite.com/wp-content/themes/my-theme-name/file-in-question.php?controller=Listings ecc....

All I need is to be able to view the php file without wordpress giving me a 404 error

I should also mention that this happens with any other php file within the theme. I can acess .html files and images (placed them on purpose its only on php file extensions.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you're getting a 404 it has nothing to do with Wordpress. Check the URL.

Comment: Hi Mike, the url is there the file is there and the path is correct i believe wordpress is blocking direct access to it as a security thing but don't know how to get around it.

Comment: wordpress doesn't allow direct access to PHP files in the theme's directory. Why can't you put the file in the root directory, or create a folder in the root and put the file there?

Comment: Good point but the only issue is that i need the header, footer and custom fields to also load in this file to keep the same look as the site.

Comment: At least, consider doing the other way around and make this work inside a page template. Why this external script wouldn't run from `functions.php`? :::: Take a look at [`wp_remote_get`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_API/wp_remote_get).

Comment: I'm with @brasofilo. Why should it not be possible to run the script internally? can you specify more?

Comment: Sure, the script calls a search function which core is located outside wordpress. I tried installing the script within wordpress but got issues with all the core cause of the same error. Basically this is a search form which calls results outside wordpress

Comment: I'd just wrap the functionality into a Wordpress plugin. There's nothing that forces you to use Wordpress  in it unless you want to, it's separate from the core and theme and hot pluggable by definition

Comment: Thanks but the script i use has licence which i cannot change.

Comment: Matanya is right. WordPress blocks direct access for security reasons, so you must put scripts into plugin files or `functions.php`. Are you saying the license doesn't allow you to use the script in your own plugin file? Then what error do you get if you put the script into `functions.php`?

Comment: I'm having this problem - did you find a fix?  Got a non-WP related PHP file in a subdirectory of my root WP install, and wordpress just shows it's 404 whenever I try and access that PHP file.

Comment: Wordpress definitely does not block direct access, unless the script trying to be used checks for this. I have seen this used multiple times successfully. Can you please post your permalink structure / .htaccess file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed by placing that file outside wordpress then called the functions within the wordpress site. Not neat but works.

Answer (score 0):

For security, WordPress wont let you go to that file directly. Your best bet is to give it a template name, assign a page to it then navigate to that page.

```
<?php
    /* Template name: Your template */
    code
?>
```

That should run the code you need and you can restrict access to public if you need to in the page settings.